# WebMatrix - Partial View Updates

Tags: partial, webmatrix

I have a simple default page that renders 3 different content pages.

```
<div style=" float:left;">
    @RenderPage("/Content/AddCounty.cshtml")
    </div>
    <div style=" float:left;width:300px;">
    @RenderPage("/Content/AddTown.cshtml")
    </div> 
    <div style=" float:none;width:300px;">
    @RenderPage("/Content/AddCompany.cshtml")
    </div>
```

These pages have kind of same fields like id, text_name. 
All of them have forms in it with Post method and submit button.
how to achieve partial update as we used to do in asp.net ?

your help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Talha

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to post the form values and update the DOM. Have a look at the [jQuery Post API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)